# Classifying indecomposable modules over $\mathbb{Z}/p^{2}\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]$

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

I'm now interested in classifying the indecomposable modules over $\mathbb{Z}/p^{2}\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]$ : the group ring of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^{2}\mathbb{Z}$.

I think that a piece of information such as an upper bound for the number of indecomposable modules whose $p$-rank is bounded by $m$ will be very helpful for my research.

Before I try by myself, I would like to hear about any known methods to classify indecomposable modules over algebra that are not necessarily over a field. Since the ring is not complicated, I hope there can be some answer.

Any references are welcome. Since I'm not an expert in the pure ring theory, I'm not familiar with many concepts like a serial ring, perfect ring,... etc. If you could suggest some ring-theoretic concepts satisfied by the ring above and which might be helpful, then it would be a great help to me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the ring is not complicated rather than simple.  People study Artin algebras (algebras over commutative artinian rings, like a finite commutative ring, that are finitely generated over the base ring as a module).  The basic Wedderburn structure theory holds.  Alternatively you are looking at $(Z/p^2)[x]/(x^p-1)\cong (Z/p^2)[x]/(x^p)$ which is a Frobenius ring.  Maybe the literature on finite commutative rings might be helpful

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, your first comment is right. I edited the question according to it. Thank you very much for the keywords, and I have found the reference 'Finite commutative rings and their applications,' and I will keep looking for other literature too. Thank you again!

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg : What is the isomorphism?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg, sorry you are right. I forgot only p^2 is 0.  Please ignore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was done by Szekeres, "Determination of a certain family of finite metabelian groups" Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 66 (1949), 1–43.

See also Nazarova & Roiter, "Finitely generated modules over a dyad of two local Dedekind rings, and finite groups which possess an abelian normal divisor of index $p$" Math USSR Izvestija 3 (1969), no. 1, 65–86, and

Aviño-Diaz & Bautista Ramon, "The additive structure of indecomposable $Z_{p^n}C_p$-modules" Comm. Algebra 24 (1996), no. 8, 2567–2595.

The answers are not easy to state, let alone prove, so good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer!